Trek equivalent(s) to 90s Hardrock, Rockhopper, Stumpjumper
It seems that there has been a movement towards doing "restomods" on 90s mountain bikes, or well-built steel frame bikes more generally, to make them comfortable cruisers. See, for example, gary's projects.
I think that this is cool, but I have no sense for which bikes are suitable/quality in the sense of having good stock components and actually being durable. I see a lot of Specialized Hardrock/Rockhopper/Stuntjumpers being used, but on Facebook Marketplace in my area they're all upwards of $200 in my area. Instead, I see many many Treks being sold for under $50 (likely due to location). I have no love for Trek, but a deal's a deal so my question is:
Which Trek models and years are close (in form or function) to the Specialized models mentioned above?
Bonus points for rigid fork models.

Assuming both bikes are in roughly the same condition...
If you have a Trek bike and a Specialized bike from the same year that sold new at the same price point you will have roughly equivalent bikes.
This is a rule of thumb not a law of physics.
Each year bike makers - like Trek and Specialized - create a line of bikes. The line of bikes is designed to have a type of bike at the price points they think the public will buy and that will compete with other bike makers. So, they will have a range of mountain bikes, or road bikes, or gravel bikes at a range of price points that roughly match each other.
If you compare a $1,000 - new, retail price (making this up, just an example) Trek mountain bike and a $1,000 Specialized mountain bike from 1995 they will be roughly (with some tradeoffs) equal.
When converting a mountain bike to a cruiser keep in mind that riding position is critical.
Many mountain bikes are designed with a leaning forward riding position.
Often, a cruiser will have a more upright riding position. On many mountain bikes, shifting to a more upright position will put a majority of rider weight on the rear wheel because the frame was designed for a forward riding position.
Too much rider weight on the rear wheel causes there to be too little weight on the front wheel causing interesting steering characteristics.

Online sites like bikepedia allow you to look up models from various years and see MSRP and component and spec summaries.
